# Python: Sometimes printing whole array instead of single word

Tags: python, arrays, list, append

Still fairly new to Python and I'm currently just making random stuff in my spare time to help me learn. Currently this is what I'm working on:

```
import sys
import random
import time
import pyperclip

print ('shit talk generator')
names = str(raw_input('Usernames: '))

splitNames = names.split(',')
splitNames.append(splitNames)


while True:   
    for x in range(1):
        iqValue = random.randint(-100,10000)
    randomName = random.choice(splitNames)
    print ('Wow %s, That was a %s IQ Play!' % (randomName, iqValue))
    clipboardCopy = 'Wow %s, That was a %s IQ Play!' % (randomName, iqValue)
    pyperclip.copy(clipboardCopy)
    print('waiting 2')
    time.sleep(2)
```

Basically, as you've gathered, just generates shit talk and saves it to my clipboard. Now, sometimes when printing the output it prints the whole array instead of a single word. Here's a snippet of the output:

```
shit talk generator
Usernames: lewis, daniel, james, john, jack, roger, fred, jones
Wow  john, That was a 1073 IQ Play!
waiting 2
Wow  roger, That was a 6182 IQ Play!
waiting 2
Wow  jack, That was a 3330 IQ Play!
waiting 2
Wow ['lewis', ' daniel', ' james', ' john', ' jack', ' roger', ' fred', ' jones', [...]], That was a 5734 IQ Play!
waiting 2
Wow ['lewis', ' daniel', ' james', ' john', ' jack', ' roger', ' fred', ' jones', [...]], That was a 4963 IQ Play!
waiting 2
Wow  fred, That was a 223 IQ Play!
waiting 2
Wow  james, That was a 7995 IQ Play!
waiting 2
Wow lewis, That was a 7620 IQ Play!
waiting 2
```

Now since this is intermittent it makes me believe that it is storing its whole self as an item in the list, am I wrong in assuming this? How would I go about fixing this and ensuring it only selects valid username from the input? Any help/guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `splitNames.append(splitNames)`  What do you expect this to do?

Comment: I'm under the impression that will add everything in splitNames to an array/list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is exactly as you say, and the culprit is this code right here:

```
splitNames = names.split(',')
splitNames.append(splitNames)
```

After you initialize `splitNames`, you're appending it to itself. Hence, by the time your function executes,

```
splitNames = ['lewis', ' daniel', ' james', ' john', ' jack', ' roger', ' fred', ' jones', ['lewis', ' daniel', ' james', ' john', ' jack', ' roger', ' fred', ' jones']]
```

Since your function chooses a random element from your list, it sometimes chooses the last element, which is the list itself. Just remove the `.append()` line and your code should work as you intend.

Comment: Removed that line and working as intended, thank you. Was under the impression something needed to be called in order to add it to a list (e.g. .append()), didn't realize splitting it already did this.

Comment: Fun fact: `splitNames` is actually more like `['a', 'b', ['a', 'b', ['a', 'b', [...]]]]`.  It's infinitely deep.  That's why their original output has `[..]` in it.  That's how python prints recursively defined lists.